# Android tablet not reading internal sdcard

Tags: sd-card, tablet

After I used sdformatter to try and fix a 0.00B internal memory problem I had with my Porto 9" 4.2 android tablet, I noticed I only made things worse because now my android mounts the internal SD card, but it doesn't show up in storage or the file manager, I now know how to fix the 0.00B internal memory problem but to do that I need my android to read my internal sdcard. By the way I used sdformatter to fully overwrite the internal sdcard by connecting it to my PC via usb

Comment: s formatter or sdformatter? (last line)

Comment: Is your SD card FAT32 formatted? Did it work before? Can you try it on another device, or another device's SD card on your tablet?

Comment: Why did you use sdformatter? Quick [Google-fu](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) Yielded that its specific for external sdcards that you can buy, **not** for internal storage which is an entirely different thing. I would hazard a guess you've really messed things up and no way of getting it back... :\